# Распарсить Xml ответ от сервера

Tags: c#, xml, xmlparser

От сервера приходит ответ

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<recognitionResults success="1"> 

<variant confidence="0">привет как дела</variant> 

</recognitionResults>
```

нужно на c# получить "привет как дела"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предпочтительней будет использовать [`XPath`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) для поиска нужного тега, а не обращаться по индексу, ибо если `xml` измениться, то и теги по преждним индексам будут другими.

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
    "<recognitionResults success=\"1\">" +
    "<variant confidence=\"0\">привет как дела</variant>" +
    "</recognitionResults>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string result = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(".//variant").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("Путь тут");
string result = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
```

Здесь мы создаем экземпляр класса `XmlDocument` для использования его методов. Сначала загружаем файл для дальнейшей работы с ним. После мы в переменную выводим текстовое значение дочерного узла по индексу 0 корневого элемента.

Answer (score 0):

`using System.Xml.Linq;`

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                        "<recognitionResults success=\"1\">" +
                        "<variant confidence=\"0\">привет как дела</variant>" +
                        "</recognitionResults>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result = doc.Root.Elements().First().Value;
```